# How to say something belongs to any of a set of things?

Tags: grammatical-number, genitive

I am an intermediate student of German and I can't figure out how to say this correctly. For example:

1. Die Lampe *ein??* der Autos (the lamp of one of the cars)
2. Die Tasche *ein??* der Jungen (the bag of one of the guys)
3. Die Schuhe *ein??* der Frauen (the shoes of one of the women)

The second I find especially puzzling. Should I say *einer* (as in Genitiv Plural) or *eines* (Genitiv Singular)?

Comment: Genitiv Singular. A great workaround, that is more widely spread than the use of Genitiv here, is "von einer/m der Frauen/Jungen/Autos".

Comment: We will not do you homework. Tell us what you believe to be right, and why you believe this

Comment: @HubertSchölnast well, false assumption on your part. I am not schooled officially and I do not get any homework. I am just interested how to say it properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have realized, for relations of *possession*, German uses the genitive rather than a preposition like in English.

The Article follows the noun it refers to, in grammatical gender, case and numerus, but in your example the article stands alone as it says "one of many" - We have a double genitive here, one in singular, the other one in plural, so

1. Die Lampe eines der Autos
2. Die Tasche eines der Jungen
3. Die Schuhe einer der Frauen

*einer* in the last example is actually **female genitive singular**. We are only talking about one single woman's shoes, no plural here, even if she is within a group of women. So the **articles** in your example are singular, the **substantives** are plural.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the two of the answers disagree on exactly the same example I am the most confused about :)

Comment: I might be wrong, but Numerus should depend on the word it belongs. I mean you say: "Das Fahrad des Jungen" und "Die Fahrräder des Jungen", nicht "Die Fahrräder der Jungen" (as long as you speak about one guy).

Comment: Well, you are right generally, but wrong in this specific example. There are **two** Genitives in the example sentences and they are *independent* in this specific example. "Die Lampe eines Autos" is one and "eines der Autos" which is the other. Note there are two "of" in the English sentences

Comment: Ah, yeah, makes sense, thank you @tofro. I was confused myself. - Never think too much about language it makes things weird :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Die Lampe eines der Autos ...
2. Die Tasche eines der Jungen ...
3. Die Schuhe einer der Frauen ...

---

However, I would suggest to make use of the word **"von"** and **Dativ** if you refer to a thing in a set of things:

1. Die Lampe von einem der Autos ...
2. Die Tasche von einem der Jungen ...
3. Die Schuhe von einer der Frauen ...

It's nowadays the more convenient approach, at least in my opinion.

Comment: It's a grammatically valid alternative, but I disagree with your last sentence: To me, as a native speaker, the first option (genitive) sounds much more sophisticated than the second option ("von" + dative). There is even a Sprichwort *"Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Tod"* for this (unfortunate) tendency to avoid the genitive in favor of the dative...

Comment: "von" stylistically better than genitive? Definitively not. Expressing possessive relationships with "von" is allowed with proper names, and some other conditions where genitive might be misleading. In all other cases it would be considered colloquial.

Comment: @Heinzi I'm a native speaker as well, and I know "Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Tod" which is by the way a book series and I would usually prefer genitive, but in that double matter it sounds more smoother to me with dative.
However with your reference you even kind of admit that the tendency in *newer* German is more dative related - I will add a *nowadays* though.

Comment: @Heinzi For this case, please use "Der Dativ ist der Tod vom Genitiv" ;)

Comment: @tofro Well, *stylistic* might be not the best wording, I changed that.

Comment: "Das Haus von der Schwiegermutter von meiner Oma" is nearly as bad as " Ernst Kuzorra seine Frau ihr Stadion" (famous quote)

Comment: @Leun4m: Indeed. I do believe, though, that the saying is older than the book series (and [Wikipedia seems to agree](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Schriftsprache_im_Vergleich_mit_der_gesprochenen_Sprache), although without reference).

Comment: @tofro That's why I would say: "Das Haus von der Schwiegermutter meiner Oma." or the other way around - One dative, one genitive - makes it more colorful, if you know what I mean, instead of making a chain of the same cases.

Comment: "1 Haus vong Oma her"?

Answer (score 1):

Bei '*die Lampe eines der Autos*' hätte ich das Problem, dass ein Auto mehr als eine Lampe hat, so dass mir der bestimmte Artikel vor 'Lampe' hier nicht gut zu passen scheint.

Bei allen drei Beispielen würde ich mich fragen, in welche Sätze diese Fragmente eingebettet sein könnten. Das zweite Beispiel könnte etwa folgendermaßen weitergeführt werden: *Die Tasche eines der Jungen wurde gestohlen.* Für meine Ohren würde jedoch '*einem der Jungen wurde die Tasche gestohlen*' sehr viel natürlicher klingen. Man könnte das Beispiel 2 auch so ergänzen: *Nach Aussagen der Polizei handelt es sich um die Tasche eines der Jungen, die seit gestern vermisst werden.* Auch hier fände ich eine andere Konstruktion weniger 'steif': *Nach Aussagen der Polizei soll die Tasche einem der Jungen gehören, die ...*

Bei den '*Schuhe(n) einer der Frauen*' erlahmt vorerst meine Phantasie, außer vielleicht '*... waren rot*', besser natürlich: *eine der Frauen trug rote Schuhe.*

Das alles sind Stilfragen. Freischwebend konstruierte Satz-Stücke mögen in sich grammatikalisch korrekt sein, ob sich für sie immer Kontexte finden lassen, in denen sie gut 'funktionieren', bleibt dahingestellt.

Wenn ich einen Grund nennen sollte, warum mir diese doppelt geknoteten Genitive nicht so sympathisch erscheinen, würde auch ich sagen, dass der Genitiv stark im Schwinden begriffen ist; er wirkt oft konstruiert, um nicht zu sagen: wie zusammenmontiert, und irgendwie unlebendig, und stört irgendwie den Fluss der Gedanken. Man möchte das, was man zu sagen hat, heutzutage gefälliger und glatter ausdrücken und nicht nebenbei durch kleine intellektuelle Knobelaufgaben abgelenkt werden. Und wie man sieht, kommt vieles auch ohne Genitiv ganz nett daher und wirkt ganz selbstverständlich.